# Filtered and abstracted NSArray of foundation objects in custom objects

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible to take an NSArray of custom objects and get an array of values from the objects in the array?

So if i had a class

```
@interface CustomObject : NSObject 
{
    NSNumber *number;
    NSString *studentName;
}
```

And an NSArray of n+ CustomObject

Is it possible to take the Array and get an NSArray of the just the NSNumber number values?

So

```
NSArray : [
    NSNumber, 
    NSNumber,
    NSNumber
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with the KVO method valueForKey:

```
NSArray *numbers = [myArray valueForKey:@"number"];
```

You can check out the method in the NSArray class reference.

Comment: I did not see this method at all. I knew about kvo but couldn't think to abstract them this way. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. You can use `valueForKey:` KVC method for getting the extracting the number from the object contained in the array.

```
NSArray *allNumbers      = [yourArray valueForKey:@"number"];
```

You can read more about [valueForKey:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/valueForKey:) in [NSKeyValueCoding Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/index.html)